# Previous Versions in Xcode 7 Version Editor

Tags: version-control, xcode7

In the Xcode 7 version editor, when displaying 2 versions of a file, there is a column between the displayed files that allows you to select the version displayed on each side of the column. For a file that has a long history, the middle column seems to extend up off the top of the screen.

Is there a way to scroll the middle column to allow selection of versions earlier than the oldest date visible when the column is first displayed? I know I can get to these earlier versions by going to the History function on the Source Control menu, but it seems like there ought to be a way to do that in the Version Editor.

Thanks

Comment: I also see the same behavior where you can't scroll the timeline. To see an old version of a file that has lots of revisions, what works for me is to click the revision in the jump bar at the bottom of the version editor. Clicking the jump bar shows a scrollable menu that allows you to choose any revision. Is using the jump bar a suitable workaround for you, or are you specifically looking for a way to find an old revision using the timeline?

Comment: Your comment is just what I was looking for. Thanks! If you make it an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to make the timeline scroll if a file has lots of revisions, but I know a workaround. Click the revision in the jump bar at the bottom of the version editor. Clicking the jump bar shows a scrollable menu where you can choose any revision of the file.